# How can I handle high traffic increase on my google cloud feature?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-play-games

My situation is the following:

I developed a game, where people can save their progress via google cloud. I'm releasing big content-updates, resulting in many people returning to my game at the same time, trying to get their savegame.

This overload causing my customers to get stucked in the savegame-loading process - not able to start playing with their progress.

Here's an [updated 4 days screenshot of the cloud-api-dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDk5R.png)
(And here's the [old "12 hours" screenshot of the cloud-api-dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeamg.png))

**more informations about the Project:**

- The game keeps using the "save in cloud"-function in the background on some stages of the game to provide players with the functionality to play on two diffrent devices.
- I'm using Unity 2019.3.9f1 and the Asset "Easy Mobile Pro 2.17.3" for the Game-Service-Feature.
- The "Google Play Games Plugin" has the version "0.10.12" and can be found [on github](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)

**more informations about the Cloud-Situation:**

- The OAuth "user type" is "External" (and can't be changed)
- The [OAuth user cap display shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmAKG.png) "0/100" for the user-cap
- And The [OAuth rate limits is displaying this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdIS3.png) for the token-grant-rate (highest "Average Token Grant Rate" is 3,33 of 10.000 as limit)
- All used quotas are within the limit. The project reaches

  - 1/10 of "queries per day" (1.000.000.000 max) and
  - 1/2 of "queries per 100 sec" (20.000 max).

**more informations about the Error-Trace in the cloud-API:**

- On my search for a better Error-Log I tried to find “Cloud Logging”-tools in the “Google Cloud Platform”-console. But every section i tried won’t display anything:

  - “Logging” (Operations tool) is empty
  - “Cloud Logging API” says: “no data available for the selected time frame.”
  - “Cloud Debugger API” says: “no data available for the selected time frame.”
- I can't find a more detailed variant of the errors as this (the "Metrics"-Section in the "Google Drive API"):
  [image: More detailed API-dashboard]
- Is there anything I miss to get a better insight?

**more informations about the Core-Code**

- As I mentioned, I’m using “EasyMobilePro”, so I have one “SaveGame”-Var and 8 calls for google and apple as well. I already contacted their support: They assured me that those calls are unchangeable & kind of rock solid (so it can’t be caused from their code) and I should try to contact google if the problem is not on my side.
- The 5 calls from EasyMobile for cloudsave are:

  - bool “GameServices.IsInitialized()”
  - void “GameServices.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution”
  - void “GameServices.WriteSavedGameData”
  - void  “GameServices.ReadSavedGameData”
  - void “GameServices.DeleteSavedGame”
- The 3 calls from EasyMobile for cloud-login are:

  - void  “GameServices.Init()”
  - delegate “GameServices.UserLoginSucceeded”
  - delegate “GameServices.UserLoginFailed”
- The Process, that causes the Issue:

  - I call “GameService.Init()”, the user logs in (no problem)
  - On that “LoginSuccess”-Callback I call my Function “HandleFirstCloudOpening”:

```cs
//This Method is Called, after the player Pressed "Save/ Load" on the StartScreen
//The button is disabled imidiately (and will be re-enabled if an error/fail happens)
public void TryCallUserLogin() {
    if (!IsLoginInit) {
        EasyMobile.GameServices.UserLoginFailed += HandleLoginFail;
        EasyMobile.GameServices.UserLoginSucceeded += HandleFirstCloudOpening;
        IsLoginInit = true;
    }
    if (!IsGameServiceInitialized) { 
        EasyMobile.GameServices.Init();
    } else { //This "else" is only be called, if the "Init" was successfull, but the player don't have a connected savegame
        HandleFirstCloudOpening();
    }
}
private void HandleLoginFail() {
    //(...) Show ErrorPopup, let the player try to login again
}
private void HandleFirstCloudOpening() {
    if (currentSaveState != CloudSaveState.NONE) {
        CloudStateConflictDebug(CloudSaveState.OPENING);
        return;
    }
    currentSaveState = CloudSaveState.OPENING;
    EasyMobile.GameServices.SavedGames.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(cloudSaveNameReference, UseFirstTimeOpenedSavedGame);
}

private void UseFirstTimeOpenedSavedGame(EasyMobile.SavedGame _savedGame, string _error) {
    currentSaveState = CloudSaveState.NONE;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_error)) {
        cloudSaveGame = _savedGame;
        ReadDataFromCloud(cloudSaveGame); 
    } else {
        ErrorPopupWithCloseButton("cloud_open", "failed with error: " + _error);
    }
}

private void ReadDataFromCloud(EasyMobile.SavedGame _savedGame) {
    if (_savedGame.IsOpen) {
        currentSaveState = CloudSaveState.LOADING;
        EasyMobile.GameServices.SavedGames.ReadSavedGameData(_savedGame, UseSucessfullLoadedCloudSaveGame);
    } else { //backup function if the fresh-opened savegame is "closed" for some reason (can happen later while "saving" ingame)
        HandleFirstCloudOpening();
    }
}

private void UseSucessfullLoadedCloudSaveGame(EasyMobile.SavedGame _game, byte[] _cloudData, string error) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error)) {
        ErrorPopupWithCloseButton("cloud_read", "Reading saved game data failed: " + error);
        return;
    }
    if (_cloudData.Length > 0) {
        //A function, that converts the saved bytes to my useable Savegame-Data
        //having a "try&catch": if it fails, it useses the callback with the param "null"
        SaveGameToByteConverter.LoadFromBytes<CoreSaveData>(_cloudData, UseSucessfullConvertedSavegameData);
    } else {
        //this will "fail", causing the use of the callback with the param "null"
        SaveGameToByteConverter.LoadFromBytes<CoreSaveData>(null, UseSucessfullConvertedSavegameData);
    }
            
}

private void UseSucessfullConvertedSavegameData(CoreSaveData _convertedSaveGame) {
    //Has a Loaded & normal SaveGame in his cloud
    if (_convertedSaveGame != null) {
        //Loaded Save matches verify-conditions
        if (CheckLoadedSaveIsVerified(_convertedSaveGame)) {
            OverrideGameSaveDatawithLoaded(_convertedSaveGame);
            ReloadCurrentScene();
            return;
        } else { //This happens if the cloud-save doesn't pass my verification-process
            ErrorPopupWithCloseButton("cloud_loadedSave", "Couldn't find a compatible Savegame!");
            return;
        }
    } else { //User uses Cloud-save for the frist Time or has an unusable savegame and gets a "new" (lost his old data)
        TrySaveGameToCloud((bool _saved) => {
            SaveAllGameFilesLocally();
        });
    }
}
```

I shrunk the code by removing most of my “if error happens, do XY”, since there are many and they would extend the reprex. If necessary I can provide a more detailed (but more complicated) code.

**current conclusion**

I can't find any issue on my side, that wouldn't have been fixed with a "restart of the game" or woudln't been covered by an error-popup for the user. It's like they are queued because of the amount of users and need to wait way too long for a response. Some users told us they had to wait & tried "x hours" (it's variable from 2h to 36h) and then they passed to play with their progress (so it worked). But some players mentioned they couldn't play again on the next day (same problem). Like their "access-token" only holds for a day?

> **Edit-History:**
>
> - **(1)** updated the first dash-board-picture to match the ongoing situation
> - **(1)** added "more informations about the cloud-situation"
> - **(1)** can't find a more detailed error-log
> - **(2)** removed most pictures as displayables (kept the links)
> - **(2)** added "more informations about the Error-Trace in the cloud-API"
> - **(2)** added "more informations about the Core-Code" and a Reprex
> - **(2)** added "current conclusion"

Comment: Do you know why do you have errors? Does it due to quota exceeded?

Comment: You should check the logs to investigate the errors. My guess is that you are being quota limited (rate limited) by Google Drive. Edit your question with details on the errors.

Comment: You will find the logs in Cloud Logging.

Comment: In addition to including the logs, may I ask that you include an [mre] of the savegame-loading function? There might be something causing a bottleneck there.

Comment: You state Cloud Logging has no information, The trouble with Cloud Logging is too much information.